# Topological invariance of intersection number

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be algebraic curves in ${\mathbb P}^2$  and  suppose they have an  isolated intersection  at  $(0,0)$. Let $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ be another such pair, and suppose that there exist neighborhoods $U$ and $\hat{U}$ of  $(0,0)$  and  a homeomorphism $\phi:U\rightarrow\hat{U}$ such that $\phi(U\cap  X)=\hat{U}\cap \hat{X}$ and $\phi(U\cap Y)=\hat{U}\cap \hat{Y}$. It seems to be well-known that the pairs $X,Y$  and $\hat{X},\hat{Y}$ have the same intersection number at $(0,0)$. Who first proved this,  and how? Where might an accessible modern  presentation be found?

Comment: it may be helpful to know that the 'reason' this number is a homeomorphism invariant is that it's equal to the linking number of the links of $X$ and $Y$ (i.e. you intersect them with the boundary of a small ball around $(0,0)$).

Comment: Have a look at Brieskorn's book *Plane Algebraic Curves*. He has a lot  historical data in that book and  you might find the answer there.

